# high memory usage when creating and removing a table on the fly using jquery

Tags: jquery, dom, memory, memory-management

i have a page that contains a date picker and a div, by selecting a date from date picker all customers of that date populated using jquery ajax and then displayed using a table.

everything works fine and customers displayed correctly.but browser memory usage grows  by removing the old table and adding another table, it seems that the old DOM objects remains in the memory....

after a while the page is useless because of very high memory usage of browser....

is there any solution to this?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({ onSelect: function (dateText, inst) { fillList(dateText) } });
    });
    function fillList(date) {
        var visitTypes = ['!', 'ویزیت اول', 'تقویم غذایی', 'رژیم', 'وزن', 'LPG', 'اندرمولب'];
        var sendTypes = ['!', 'حضوری', 'فکس', 'ایمیل', 'پیک', 'پست', 'تلفن', 'وب سایت'];
        var statusIcons = ['', 'i_w', 'i_vt', 'i_v', 'i_vt', 'i_f', 'i_e', 'i_en', 'i_fas', 'i_fr'];
        $.ajax({ url: "../CustomControls/ReceptionHandler.ashx?date=" + date, context: document.body, success: function (result) {
            var items = $.parseJSON(result);
            var i = 0;
            $table = $('<table/>').attr({ 'id': 'listitems', 'cellpadding': '1', 'cellspacing': '1' }).css({ 'width': '100%', 'background-color': '#494949', 'text-align': 'center', 'font-weight': 'bold' });
            $head = $('<tr/>').attr('class', 'HeaderStyle');
            $head.append($('<td/>').attr('class', 'r').html('ردیف'));
            $head.append($('<td/>').attr('class', 'i'));
            $head.append($('<td/>').attr('class', 'p').html('نام-نام خانوادگی'));
            $head.append($('<td/>'));
            $head.append($('<td/>').attr('class', 'v').html('ویزیت'));
            $head.append($('<td/>'));
            $head.append($('<td/>').attr('class', 't').html('ساعت'));
            $head.append($('<td/>').attr('class', 'o').html('عملیات'));
            $table.append($head);
            $.each(items, function () {
                r = $('<tr/>');
                if (i % 2 == 0) {
                    r.attr('class', 'RowStyle');
                }
                else {
                    r.attr('class', 'AlternatingRowStyle');
                }
                r.append($('<td/>').html(++i));
                r.append($('<td/>').attr('class', statusIcons[this.status]));
                r.append($('<td/>').attr('class', this.id).html((this.name + ' ' + this.family)));
                r.append($('<td/>').html((this.send != undefined ? sendTypes[this.send] : '')));
                r.append($('<td/>').html(visitTypes[this.vtype]));
                r.append($('<td/>'));
                r.append($('<td/>').html(this.time));
                r.append($('<td/>'));
                $table.append(r);
            });
            $("#listitems").remove();
            $("#list").append($table);
        }
        });
    }

</script>

 <div id="toolbar" style="width: 100%;">
     <input id="datepicker" type="text" />
 </div>
 <div id="list" style="width: 100%;">
 </div>
```

update: i also used this method , but problem not solved:

```
                       var output = '<table style=\'width:100%;background-color:#494949;text-align:center;font-weight:bold;\' cellpadding=\'1\' cellspacing=\'1\'>';
                            output += '<tr class=\'HeaderStyle\'>';
                            output += '<td class=\'r\'>ردیف</td>';
                            output += '<td class=\'i\'></td>';
                            output += '<td class=\'p\'>نام-نام خانوادگی</td>';
                            output += '<td></td>';
                            output += '<td class=\'v\'>ویزیت</td>';
                            output += '<td></td>';
                            output += '<td class=\'t\'>ساعت</td>';
                            output += '<td class=\'o\'>عملیات</td>';
                            output += '</tr>';
                            $.each(items, function () {
                                i % 2 == 0 ? output += '<tr class=\'RowStyle\'>' : output += '<tr class=\'AlternatingRowStyle\'>';
                                output += '<td>' + ++i + '</td>';
                                output += '<td class=\'' + statusIcons[this.status] + '\'></td>';
                                output += '<td class=\'' + this.id + '\' onmouseout=\'hd();\' onmouseover=\'sd2(\'' + this.id + '\');\'>' + this.name + ' ' + this.family + '</td>';
                                output += '<td>' + (this.send != undefined ? sendTypes[this.send] : '') + '</td>';
                                output += '<td>' + visitTypes[this.vtype] + '</td>';
                                output += '<td></td>';
                                output += '<td>' + this.time + '</td>';
                                output += '<td></td>';
                                output += '</tr>';
                            });
                            output += '</table>';
              $("#list").html('');
            $("#list").html(output);
```

Comment: Does this happen in every browser, or which ones have you tested?

Comment: [jquery performance rules](http://www.artzstudio.com/2009/04/jquery-performance-rules/). Kindly read [number 6](http://www.artzstudio.com/2009/04/jquery-performance-rules/#limit-dom-manipulation) in that article. :)

Comment: there isn't any difference in all browsers

Answer (score 0):

user ,

Construct your string and use finally .append.

don't use so many appends , append is very costly operation

do all your string manipulation in a string until it is finished

a sample example

instead of this

```
var lihtml = "<li class='green'>this is a test text</li>",
        listring = "";

    function populatelist() {
            for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            $('#listparent').append("test");
            }    


        }
```

this will be good

```
var lihtml = "<li class='green'>this is a test text</li>",
    listring = "";

function populatelist() {
        for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            listring += lihtml;
        }    

        $('#listparent').append(listring);

    }
```

Comment: He isn't using `.append` on an element inside the DOM, so that shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: @Marcus , he is using ...append dynamically so many times which is not good

Comment: @gov, sure he's using it redundantly - but it doesn't explain the memory leak.

Comment: @Reigel, direct DOM manipulation is only made with `$("#listitems").remove();` and `$("#list").append($table);`, and they are both outside the loop. Did I miss anything?

Comment: I'm back! :) well, addressing Marcus's comment, look at this [test](http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/BpbhW/). Try looking at the console while you're at it.

Comment: @Reigel, Thanks for that test. I must say that is both surprising and interesting. Now I need to research why - since it doesn't directly insert anything into the DOM until after the loop.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5xXDk/

the problem does not related to the table creation speed and memory usage, the problem is that when someone working a while on the page and selecting dates over time old tables added to the page removed from display but not removed from memory. for example memory usage grows from initial size of 100 MB in firefox 4b10 to 500 MB after 50 times selecting date from datepicker!

Comment: @Marcus - all I can say is that `.append()` is costly versus string concatenation. :)

Comment: @Alireza - sorry about that. hmmm... in your link, yes it does grow. I'm still checking...

Comment: @Reigel, well it's obvious that native js would be faster, but that it would be that much faster and that there isn't really much different between .append in loop with or without direct manipulation makes me shrug. Edit: Updated [your test](http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/BpbhW/1/) with a third that does direct DOM manipulation in the loop.

Comment: http://alireza-salehi.persiangig.com/image/1.JPG
 http://alireza-salehi.persiangig.com/image/2.JPG
 http://alireza-salehi.persiangig.com/image/3.JPG

Answer (score 0):

What I immediately noticed is the lack of chaining, which is one of many powerful features in jQuery. John Resig wrote on his blog about [ultra-chaining](http://ejohn.org/blog/ultra-chaining-with-jquery/) that you'd might want to take a look at.

Other then that, I can't really see where the problem is. This rather seems to be a browser-related problem rather then a jQuery-related one.

Comment: then this may amaze you. :) [jquery performance rules](http://www.artzstudio.com/2009/04/jquery-performance-rules/#limit-dom-manipulation)

Comment: @Reigel, I know all of that. What I do not know is where this guys is doing direct DOM manipulation in a loop - other then that he's using `.append` redundantly :)

Comment: the problem does not related to the table creation speed and memory usage, the problem is that when someone working a while on the page and selecting dates over time old tables added to the page removed from display but not removed from memory. 
for example memory usage grows from initial size of 100 MB in firefox 4b10  to 500 MB after 50 times selecting date from datepicker!